# Прогресс выполнения запроса в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Существует ли возможность в MySQL получить информацию о прогрессе выполнения длительного запроса? Интересна информация о том, сколько осталось или сколько уже выполнено (например, в ед. времени, процентах) на основании некоей оценки общего объёма предполагаемой работы над запросом от самой СУБД.

Comment: Какой-то у вас неправильный запрос.

Comment: @Visman, почему? Существуют же длительные запросы просто по причине большого объёма данных. Речь же не идёт об оптимизации скорости выполнения запроса. Она может устраивать или упираться в потолок по некоторым причинам. Но тем не менее хотелось бы иметь возможность наблюдать за прогрессом выполнения.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что такое есть. ни в одной БД штатных средств не встречал.